# Не выполняется hide

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var textH1 = $('#main_h1').text('БУМ БУМ БУМ');

$('img[src*=logo.jpg]').hide(3000);

}); //Конец ready
```

`logo.jpg` не исчезает. Почему?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('img[src*="logo.jpg"]').hide();
```